# Get row number when using "MAXIFS" function

Tags: excel-2016

I am using `MAXIFS` (or similar) to identify the wanted line in a table. but i do not need the max value, i need data from an adjecent column. Example:

```
=MAXIFS(TableComments1[CommentDate];TableComments1[T.Number];TableView1[@Number])
```

Basically, in this example i am searching for lines, matching `"Number"`, with the latest date. But in a next step i require to get the row number of the date to enable the use of `INDEX` and return the appropriate column (`TableComments1[Comment]`).

I tried different approaches - no success. 
PS: performance is also important here.

UPDATE, example lookup table:`"TableComments1"`

```
T.Number      | Comment      | CommentDate
==============+==============+===========
SCTASK0073347 | correction   | 22/07/2018
SCTASK0073347 | update 11    | 25/07/2018
SCTASK0073347 | update 2     | 21/07/2018
```

PS: sorting `"CommentDate"` is not an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of dabbling and finally posting the above question i found a solution myself. Not sure it is the best but performance seems okay.

Be aware: a more simple solution is possible, by sorting the table "`CommentDate`". This could not be guaranteed and was not desired in this use-case based on the question input.

recap: We want in table `TableView1` to add the most recent comment for column "`Number`" with lookup from `TableComments1` containing the comment history:

I got the idea from another post to use a helper column for combination of 2 criteria. New table layout:

```
T.Number      | Comment      | CommentDate | Helper1
==============+==============+=============+===================
SCTASK0073347 | correction   | 22/07/2018  | 43303SCTASK0073347
SCTASK0073347 | find this!   | 25/07/2018  | 43306SCTASK0073347
SCTASK0073347 | update 2     | 21/07/2018  | 43302SCTASK0073347
TASK9999      | comment      | 25/07/2018  | 43306TASK9999
```

Formula breakdown

The formula for the Helper column just does CONCATENATE 2 columns:

```
 =[@CommentDate]&[@[T.Number]]
```

Lets say we want: `SCTASK0073347`
Note: in the helper column we have value "`43306SCTASK0073347`"; 
where "`43306`" is the numerical representation of date "`25/07/2018`".

This will search for a match of "`Number`" and return the most recent "`CommentDate`":

```
=MAXIFS(TableComments1[CommentDate];TableComments1[T.Number];TableView1[@Number])
```

Returning "`25/07/2018`". Lets abbreviate the above to `<<MostRecentDate>>` for readability in next step(s).

This step, will search for a combination of above formula `<<MostRecentDate>>` & "`Number`" in the Helper column:

```
 =MATCH(<<MostRecentDate>>&TableView1[@Number];TableComments1[Helper1];0)
```

..returning row number (`2`) matching helper table value "`43306SCTASK0073347`".

From this point forward we use `MATCH` (now returning the wanted row) and `INDEX` in a style VLOOKUP would do:

```
 =INDEX(TableComments1[Comment];MATCH(<<MostRecentDate>>&TableView1[@Number];TableComments1[Helper1];0))
```

...returning the wanted column with desired comment "`find this!`".

Full/final formula, includes `IFNA` function to clear blank lookups with no comments:

```
 =IFNA(INDEX(TableComments1[Comment];MATCH(MAXIFS(TableComments1[CommentDate];TableComments1[T.Number];TableView1[@Number])&TableView1[@Number];TableComments1[Helper1];0));"")
```